# Play mp3 on iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari, webkit

Is it possible to play embedded MP3 on iPad Safari (the way you do on normal desktop browsers) ?

If yes, do we need to code separately for iPad Safari ?

The reason I am asking is bcoz in my app, the desktop code for mp3 is not working on iPad..
The code for desktop is

```
<EMBED src="'+audioUrl+'" autostart=true loop=false volume=100 hidden=true>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the excellent answers of Blindy and John, the IPad should be HTML5 compliant which means that you can use the HTML5 audio and vido tags. You can read more about this at [The Safari Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the `<audio>` tag, that's what it's there for.

To answer your question, yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML 5 `<audio>` tag. Check out [w3schools - HTML5 Audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp).

There is also a table on there telling you what formats work with what browsers.

Comment: Thx a lot..Even though the table lists support for Safari 3, I wanted to know if the audio element is supported on iPad Safari..

Comment: @hmthr [Apple Dev Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/HTMLTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001262-SW2) - Supported in iOS 3 and later

Comment: Excellent ref...thx..just one last question..is html5 the only way for ipad safari audio..i m asking this as i want the same page to work in desktop browsers..and i think not all of them have good html5 support as of now ...

Comment: @hmthr - I guess you could always detect it's safari mobile and use the <audio> tag, and if it's a browser that doesn't support that tag then replace it with another method/support.